# result not showing when looping

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm doing a powershell which runs through a loop to get result from an sql query with different parameters. the issue is only the first run of loop has a result. the rest all blank result which should also show some result.

```
$Days = @(90,60,30,15)
$Start = 0
$End = 0
$Affiliation = 1
for ($i = 0 ; $i -lt $Affiliation.Count ; $i++) { 
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Days.Count ; $i++){
    if ($Days[$i] -eq 1) {
        $End = $Days[$i]
        $Start = 0
        write-host "Start/End r:" $Start $End
    } 
    elseIf ($index -eq $Days.Length) {
        $End = $Days[$i]
        $Start = 0
        write-host "Start/End m:" $Start $End 
    }
    else {
        $End = $Days[$i]
        $Start = $Days[$i+1] + 1
        write-host "Start/End s:" $Start $End
    }
          ########## Queries

        $Querydays = " SELECT 
        distinct tblcustomer.CustomerName AS Customer_Name
        , tblsma.sorno AS SMA_SOR_Number
        , FUNC_GET_JSON_VALUES('Name', tblsma.products) AS Products
        , DATE_FORMAT(tblsma.expiryDate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Expiry_Date
        , tblsma.Remarks AS 'Remarks'
        , DATEDIFF( DATE(tblsma.expiryDate), CURDATE()) AS Days_Left_Before_Expiration 
         #,GROUP_CONCAT(tblsma.products) AS 'PRODUCT'
        FROM
        where 
        tblcustomer.affiliationID = '" + $Affiliation[$i] + "'
        and tblcustomer.affiliationID <> 95
        and tblaccountsgroup.GroupID <> 5
        and datediff(DATE(tblsma.expiryDate), CURDATE()) between " + $Start + " and " + $End + "
        order by Days_Left_Before_Expiration DESC"
        #####################
        $ResultDays=$null
        $ResultDays = MysqlConn -Query $Querydays
        Write-Host $ResultDays
        $EmailBody =  $EmailBody + "`r `n" + "<b>List of Valid License that will due in next " + $Days[$i] + " days:</b>"
        foreach($row in $ResultDays)
        {
            $EmailBody = "`n" + $EmailBody + "`r `n" + "Account Name : " + $row.Item(0) + "`r" +
            "SOR No.      : " + $row.Item(1) + "`r" +
            "Product Name : " + $row.Item(2) + "`r" +
            "Expiry Date  : " + $row.Item(3) + "`r" +
            "Remarks      : " + $row.Item(4) + "`r" +
            "Days Before Expiry : " + $row.Item(5) + "`r" +
            "`n"  
        } 
    $rep = $Days[$i+1]
}
}

Start/End s: 61 90
System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow
Start/End s: 31 60

Start/End s: 16 30

Start/End s: 1 15
```

Comment: `$affiliation` is not an array here but you are treating it as such with `$affiliation.count` and `$affiliation[$i]`. Why is that?

Comment: Change the variable name `$i` of the second `for` loop because you use two times the `$i` so this will be overwritten all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use in both `for`loops the same variable `$i` this will be overwritten all the time. Change the name of one of them.

Bad:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i ++)
{
    ('First for loop: ' + $i)

    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i ++)
    {
        ('Second for loop: ' + $i)
    }
}
First for loop: 1
Second for loop: 1
Second for loop: 2
Second for loop: 3
Second for loop: 4
Second for loop: 5
Second for loop: 6
Second for loop: 7
Second for loop: 8
Second for loop: 9
Second for loop: 10
```

Good:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i ++)
{
    ('First for loop: ' + $i)

    for ($x = 1; $x -lt 11; $x ++)
    {
        ('Second for loop: ' + $x)
    }
}
First for loop: 1
Second for loop: 1
Second for loop: 2
Second for loop: 3
Second for loop: 4
Second for loop: 5
Second for loop: 6
Second for loop: 7
Second for loop: 8
Second for loop: 9
Second for loop: 10
First for loop: 2
Second for loop: 1
Second for loop: 2
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that I'm using the same variable for the two loops.